# Access an attribute from a returned object in c#

Tags: c#

Good Day.
I am struggling with what I would assume would be a novice issue, I have an object being returned from a method in my data layer, but I want to be able to access say

RuleListCollection.ruleName

but I have the whole object sent back to me in the list, how can i access the attribute above.
here is the code from the data layer where the object is returned

```
        public List<TpRuleMapConfig>  GetTpRuleList()
    {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        TpRuleMapConfig tpRuleMapConfig = new TpRuleMapConfig();
        List<TpRuleMapConfig> tpRuleList = new List<TpRuleMapConfig>();


        try
        {
            query.AppendLine("SELECT maestro.TPRuleMapConfig.LINK,maestro.TPRuleMapConfig.TPRULENAME,maestro.TPRuleMapConfig.SBSARULENAME,");
            query.AppendLine(" maestro.COUNTINGCONFIG.RULETYPE,maestro.TPRuleMapConfig.ISPREADVRULE FROM maestro.TPRuleMapConfig");
            query.AppendLine("INNER JOIN maestro.COUNTINGCONFIG on maestro.COUNTINGCONFIG.NAME=TPRuleMapConfig.SBSARULENAME;");

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(this._connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query.ToString()))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            tpRuleMapConfig.Link = reader["LINK"].ToString();
                            tpRuleMapConfig.TpRuleName = reader["TPRULENAME"].ToString();
                            tpRuleMapConfig.SbsaRuleName = reader["SBSARULENAME"].ToString();
                            tpRuleMapConfig.RuleType = Convert.ToInt32(reader["RULETYPE"]);
                            tpRuleMapConfig.IsPreadVised = reader["ISPREADVRULE"].GetBooleanValue();

                            tpRuleList.Add((tpRuleMapConfig));
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return tpRuleList;
    }
```

and here is where I want to access that value

```
        DataLayer datalayer = new DataLayer(this._connectionString);
        cmbRuleType.DataSource = datalayer.GetTpRuleList().TpRuleName;
```

Comment: from `GetTpRoleList()` you get a List, so you have to access an element via index. `datalayer.GetTpRuleList()[0].TpRuleName`

Comment: So is `TpRuleName` the same for every item in the list? If so, you can just use the first one - `cmbRuleType.DataSource = datalayer.GetTpRuleList().First().TpRuleName;` (with an appropriate check that there are values in the list)

Comment: `TpRuleName` does not exist on the *list*, it exists on elements in the list. So if the data varies, you could have as many values as elements in the lists.

Comment: `GetTpRuleList` returns a list of `TpRuleMapConfig` so you can not access the property directly on the list. The list will have multiple objects in it. So which object's property do you want to access?

Answer (score 3):

Your method returns a `List` of objects not a single object. You can iterate over the list and read the `RuleName` of each object in the list.

```
var tpRuleList = datalayer.GetTpRuleList();
foreach (var tpRule in tpRuleList)
{
    var tpRuleName = tpRule.TpRuleName;
    // Do something with tpRuleName.
}
```